# how to store an image path for an image loaded in imageview android

Tags: android, image

the user will select an image that will later be uploaded on his command without selecting the image themselves. I have tried some of the option on SO but the option i used seems to be replicating a black image and storing its own path. I need the same image to be used and uploaded please help.

the code for the saving is as follows:

```
 public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
```

and the code i am using to then get this image later is:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(submissions.getLinkToDoc());
                documents.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
where submissions.getLinkToDoc() is the path stored by the code above.
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain it properly?

Comment: the problem i am facing is how to store the exact image path for the image the user has selected. This code seems to be creating a second image in the gallery and the image it is creating is just a black image. I need the exact path of the selected image so that later i can use it in that second bit of code

Comment: Probably shared preferences might help

Comment: even if they are collected and used in the same activity?